# kotlin how to share common retrofit response handler code

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

Having code to get from two different endpoints,  but the response json have same scheme and the response handler code are same.

```
internal interface DataApi {
    @GET("/api/api_1")
    fun getData_1(@QueryMap params: Map<String, String>?): Call<DataMpdel>


    @GET("/api/api_2")
    fun getData_2(@QueryMap params: Map<String, String>?): Call<DataMpdel>
}

private lateinit var dataApi: DataApi

init {
    dataApi = createDataApi()
}

private fun createDataApi() : DataApi {
    val restAdapter = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(getGsonConverterFactory())
            .build()
    return restAdapter.create(DataApi::class.java)
}
```

It could use if/else to call the different endpoint, but that will duplicate the handler code.

**Update:** create the handler function and in both onResposne() just call that function.

Any suggestion to be better with shared handler code?

```
private fun fetchFirst(){

    if (!UseDataApi_1) {
        //
        dataApi. getData_1(getQueryParams()).enqueue(object : Callback<DataModel> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DataModel>?, response: Response<DataModel>?) {

              // same handler code 
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DataModel>?, throwable: Throwable?) {

      // same error handler code 

            }
        })
    } else {
        //
        dataApi. getData_1(getQueryParams()).enqueue(object : Callback<DataModel> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<DataModel>?, response: Response<DataModel>?) {

              // same handler code 
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DataModel>?, throwable: Throwable?) {

      // same error handler code

            }
        }) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is calling getData_1 for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to minimize the duplicate code, create the callback as a class object and use it for both calls (something like this):

```
private val callback = object : Callback<DataModel> {
   override fun onResponse(call: Call<DataModel>?, response: Response<DataModel>?) {
       // handler code 
   }

   override fun onFailure(call: Call<DataModel>?, throwable: Throwable?) {
       // error handler code 
   }
}

private fun fetchFirst() {
    if (UseDataApi_1) {
        dataApi.getData_1(getQueryParams()).enqueue(callback)
    } else {
        dataApi.getData_2(getQueryParams()).enqueue(callback)
    }
}
```